# Q ZAPIER curl request

Tags: curl, zapier

How can i reformat this request to make work in a zapier webhook.

curl --basic --user user:password https://ibm-watson-ml.mybluemix.net/v3/identity/token

what will be the correct sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue.

if you have this same issue use the following request in zapier.

Only the url, get request.

and basic authentication.